# Objects disappearing once constructor finishes

Tags: c#, mef

I suspect there is a term for this behavior that, if I knew it, I could google it and learn what I need. However, I don't know it.

Here is my constructor:

```
[Export(typeof(MainWindowViewModel))]
public class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private readonly IProductService _productService;
    private readonly IProfileService _profileService;
    public IEnumerable<ProductViewModel> Products { get; private set; }
    private ProductViewModel _productSelected;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public MainWindowViewModel(IProductService productService, IProfileService profileService, ILoggingService logger)
    {
        Products = _productService.InstalledProducts.Select(p => new ProductViewModel(p, _profileService, _logger));
        SelectTheProductInDirectoryRunningFrom();

        _productSelected.Load();
    }

    protected virtual void SelectTheProductInDirectoryRunningFrom()
    {
        string currentDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

        if (_productSelected != null && _productSelected.InstalledPath != null &&
                !_productSelected.InstalledPath.Contains(currentDir))
        {
            _productSelected =
                Products.Where(p => currentDir.Contains(p.InstalledPath)).Select(p => p).DefaultIfEmpty(
                    _productSelected).SingleOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

It seems pretty self-explanatory. It builds a collection of `ProductViewModel`s, finds the relevant one, and calls `Load()` on it. `ProductViewModel.Load()` contains this code:

```
public class ProductViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private readonly IProfileService _profileService;
    private readonly ILoggingService _logger;
    private ObservableCollection<ProfileViewModel> _profiles;
    private ConfigProfile _defaultConfig;
    private ProfileViewModel _currentProfile;
    public ListCollectionView Profiles { get; set; }

public bool Load(string errorMessage, bool critical)
{
    List<ProfileViewModel> profileVms = new List<ProfileViewModel> { _currentProfile };

    profileVms.AddRange(
        _profileService.GetSavedProfiles(_data.ProductType).Select(
            p =>
            {
                p.FilePath = current.FilePath;
                return new ProfileViewModel(p, _defaultConfig, _profileService) { IsChanged = false };
            }));
    _profiles = new ObservableCollection<ProfileViewModel>(profileVms);

    Profiles = new ListCollectionView(_profiles);
    Profiles.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("ProfileTypeValue", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
    Profiles.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("ProfileName", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
    Profiles.CurrentChanged += (sender, args) =>
    {
        ((ProfileViewModel)Profiles.CurrentItem).Initialize();
        _currentProfile = Profiles.CurrentItem as ProfileViewModel;
    };

    return true;
}
```

When I step through this code in the visual studio debugger, everything executes and both `_profiles` and `Profiles` are assigned to correctly. However, when execution returns from the `MainWindowViewModel` constructor, `_profiles` and `Profiles` are both null.

[image]

I press F11 twice to arrive here:

[image]

What could be going wrong? Are my objects somehow passing out of scope? I thought maybe it had something to do with value vs reference but I can't find anything. Thanks!

Comment: Could it be the fact that you are apparently using class fields (e.g. `_productService` instead of the parameters passed to the constructor (e.g. `_productService`)?  Could it be deferred execution that is getting triggered by the debugger but not during execution?

Comment: You need to show us the declarations in context of the code.

Comment: @RBarryYoung How's that?

Comment: Am I missing something?  Where is `Profiles` declared?

Comment: @DStanley They are both null in the debugger after execution returns from the constructor. I inspect them while inside `Load()` and they are assigned to. I press F11 a few times and they are all of a sudden null.

Comment: Show us the declarations of these variables, and where they are in relation to the code snippets that you have shown us.

Comment: @CodingGorilla I've reorganized my question hopefully to be more clear.

Comment: @sirdank That helps.  So my first thought is: Is it possible you're getting more than one instance of `MainWindowViewModel`?  Because as long as you're working with the same instance it's members should not just _magically_ disappear.  Another thing to look at is whether either of those variables are changed anywhere else in the code, maybe it's being overwritten somewhere.

Comment: @CodingGorilla I don't think it is and I don't believe either of the variables are being changed elsewhere.

Comment: @sirdank - to see if you are really working with multiple instances or not add a field to the class `private Guid tempId = Guit.NewGuid();`. This should produce a random enough id. Do your test again with the above screen shots and see if you have the same id appear for both screenshots, if so then the value is being changed from outside/inside but otherwise it will prove that you are indeed working with 2 complete separate instances which would explain symptom although you would still need to investigate where the 2nd instance is being created where you expect the 1st.

Comment: @sirdank I can guarantee you that the field and the property **are** being changed somewhere, they won't change on their own.  Their scope is an instance of the `ProductViewModel` so they would not go out of scope.  As someone once said, "when you eliminate the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth." :)

Comment: If it turns out that the instances are the same then the value is being changed from outside/inside that class. To figure out when/where this is happening I would temporarily change your field to a property with a backing field and put a break point in the setter. Changing all access to a setter and getter method would also work. You could set a conditional breakpoint to see when the field was being changed to NULL or just a normal breakpoint to see all changes to the field.

Comment: @Igor It's definitely the same instance and I used the backing field to make sure it wasn't being modified. I think it has something to do with the `Products` IEnumerable not updating or something but I don't know why it would do that. I added the code for `SelectTheProductInDirectoryRunningFrom`.

Comment: @sirdank - all signs are pointing to that you have 2 instances of that container object or you happen to be retrieving the wrong instance of it (in your 2nd screenshot where the nulls are there are 2 instances in the list). It would be very easy to prove if you added a Guid as field with an auto created value as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: @Igor Sorry, earlier I tried that with `MainWindowViewModel` and it was the same. I tried it with my `Instance_2` `ProductViewModel` and you are right, there are two of them. I am confused now though since I don't know how that can be happening with my `SelectTheProductInDirectoryRunningFrom` code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning to an object from a `WhereSelectEnumerableIterator` creates a new object so the original list wasn't being updated.

```
_productSelected =
    Products.Where(p => currentDir.Contains(p.InstalledPath)).Select(p => p).DefaultIfEmpty(
        _productSelected).SingleOrDefault();
```

I added a `.ToList()` onto this call

```
Products = _productService.InstalledProducts.Select(p => new ProductViewModel(p, _profileService, _logger));
```

to force the `IEnumerable` into a `List` which does not create a new object and does update the existing one. Thanks @Igor.